# How to restart DSL modem betweenwhiles automatically

Tags: software-rec, internet-connection, dsl-modem

I have a standard ADSL cable modem. My ISP is troublesome and sometimes internet connection goes off until I have to restart the modem. I usually leave my PC open while I'm out. So if the connection goes off, a software should restart the modem periodically, e.g. once an hour. Is there a software that can do this?

OS: Windows 7

Comment: Which cable modem? Could you access it by a web interface? Could you telnet it?

Comment: It's Yaksu S200 ADSL router modem. I can access its interface via my web browser. I don't know about telnet. Here is the product page I could found: http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:lNRBlPfxLEUJ:www.yaksu.com.tr/eng/s200.asp+yaksu+adsl+modem&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to try:

**Software:**

- [WinRouter Restarter](http://harisoft.net.tf/index_files/Page597.htm)
- [Imran's Broadband Helper Utility](http://imran-utilities.synthasite.com/)

**Telnet:**
(according the product page telnet remote management is supported)
so try this in a command prompt:

1. Telnet "the ip of your router" (generally 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1)
2. You will be prompted for user name & password  (if it's not set, generaly admin/admin or root/root or look in the manual)
3. Try "reboot" or "restart" (or "help" or "?" to find the similar command)

If it's succesful you could use [tst10](http://jerrymannel.com/blog/2008/11/11/telnet-scripting-tool-aka-tst10exe/) to create a script and add it to your scheduler (you could also test your connection in the script...)

**Web interface:**
differents ways:

- Sometimes the reset command is called by a simple html, so a shortcut to this page (in scheduler) will do the trick.
- With the firefox extensions [Live Http Header](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/3829) or [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1843) you could inspect what's sended by the web interface when you reboot the modem, to reproduce it in a more convenient way
- [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/) (script engine using screenshots)
- [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (powerfull script/macro engine)